# Differences between QuantileTransformer and PowerTransformer

Tags: scikit-learn

In sklearn, the document of QuantileTransformer says

> This method transforms the features to follow a uniform or a **normal distribution**

the document of PowerTransformer says,

> Apply a power transform featurewise to make data more **Gaussian-like**

It seems both of them can transform features to a gaussian/normal distribution. What are the differences in terms of this aspect and when to use which ?

Comment: Please see the intro and NOTE in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info

Answer (score 1):

The main difference is `PowerTransformer()` being parametric and `QuantileTransformer()` being non-parametric. Box-Cox or Yeo-Johnson will make your data look more 'normal' (i.e. less skewed and more centered) but it's often still far from the perfect gaussian. `QuantileTransformer(output_distribution='normal')` results usually look much closer to gaussian, at the cost of distorting linear relationships somewhat more. I believe there's no rule of thumb to decide which one would work better in a certain case, but it's worth noting you can select an optimal scaler in a pipeline when doing e.g. `GridSearchCV()`.

Answer (score 0):

It is confusing terminology that they use because Gaussian and normal distribution are actually the SAME.

QuantileTransformer and PowerTransformer are both non-linear.

To answer your question about what exactly is the difference it is this according to https://scikit-learn.org:

"QuantileTransformer provides non-linear transformations in which distances between marginal outliers and inliers are shrunk. PowerTransformer provides non-linear transformations in which data is mapped to a normal distribution to stabilize variance and minimize skewness. "

Source and more info here: [https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/preprocessing/plot_all_scaling.html#:~:text=QuantileTransformer%20provides%20non%2Dlinear%20transformations,stabilize%20variance%20and%20minimize%20skewness](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/preprocessing/plot_all_scaling.html#:%7E:text=QuantileTransformer%20provides%20non%2Dlinear%20transformations,stabilize%20variance%20and%20minimize%20skewness).